# Use a dynamic value in ng-repeat value

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

How do I get the values within the object to iterate over based on filterOption? Width or Height? Do I need to bind to a model? Most of the other questions that are anything like this have to do with models.

**Goal:** `ng-repeat="section in prefs.filter.DYNAMIC_VALUE_FROM_filterOption`

**Doesn't output anything:** 
`ng-repeat="section in prefs.filter[0]`

**Successful but not dynamic - width is hardcoded.**
ng-repeat="section in prefs.filter.width"

FIDDLE http://jsfiddle.net/xyp6y1ap/2/

JAVASCRIPT

```
function MainCtrl($scope) {

    $scope.prefs = {
        atts: ['width', 'height'],
        filter: {
            width: ['160', '180', '300', '728'],
            height: ['90', '150', '250', '600'],

        },
        filterOption: 1

    };

}
```

REPEATER IN HTML

```
       ng-repeat="section in prefs.filter.DYNAMIC_VALUE"

       ng-repeat="section in prefs.filter.width"
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Just like you would do in JavaScript.

`$scope.prefs.filterOption` is, I assume, the index in the array `$scope.prefs.atts` of the attribute that you want to iterate over.

So the name of the attribute is `$scope.prefs.atts[$scope.prefs.filterOption]`.

And the actual array you want to iterateover is thus

```
$scope.prefs.filter[$scope.prefs.atts[$scope.prefs.filterOption]]
```

So you want, in your HTML

```
ng-repeat="section in prefs.filter[prefs.atts[prefs.filterOption]]"
```

This is extremely convoluted, though. The point of the controller is to provide an easy to use model to the view. Instead of dynamically setting the value of an index, which itself allows accessing the name of an attribute, which itself allows accessing an array of widths or heights, you should simply dynamically set a variable pointing to the array itself.

Answer (score 0):

You can use key,value pair in ng-repeat like:

```
<section ng-repeat="item in prefs.filter">
    <section ng-repeat="(key,value) in item">
        {{value}}
    </section>
</section>

http://plnkr.co/edit/IPY2YUWLlquWKI7I5MM2?p=preview
```